# Video live streaming using UDP in python

Tags: python, udp, video-streaming, live-streaming

I have a project that works with video processing. I have many clients who send live video and one service that receives and processes the videos. The client is a Raspberry Pi that captures video and sends it to the service. The service is a Python module, which receives the video from all clients, and process them. Let's suppose that the client sends video at 24 FPS, and the service can process only 8 FPS. So, the service would need to take the newest frame, and drop others. In this case, it would take 1 frame and drop 2. In principle, audio is not required.

So, I want to know if there is a Python library to transmit video live streaming using UDP protocol.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The question is not crystal clear, but I deduce that..

- You have several rtsp cameras, sending, say H264 video
- In you rasperry pi you have processes that receive and decode the video.  In addition to that, you want to do some image analysis, etc. for the decoded (yuv or rgb) bitmaps
- Your rasp pi can't keep up with the pace, so the processes analyzing the video will be missing some frames

Right?

There's a python library that can stream video from several sources, decode the video and distribute it among python multiprocesses.  Check out the tutorial in

http://www.valkka.fi

The learning curve might be a bit steep, but if you follow the tutorial from lesson 1, you'll be fine.

(disclaimer: I did that)